# POSIX Message Queue is supported on which linux Kernel

Tags: linux, message-queue

I could successfully implement POSIX Message Queue on **Ubuntu 10.04** (Kernel version 2.6.38). 
But the code fails when (built and) run on same version of Ubuntu 10.04 (Kernel version 2.6.37) on **ARM** Processor (Thin client devices like HP T410).

The failure happens to use any of the Message Queue functions (e.g. mq_open, unlink_message_queue()) :

OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented

Online information shows that. POSIX MQ is supported from Linux Kernel version 2.6.6. 
This is very confusing to me (being new to linux world).

How come the functionality works on a x86 Linux Kernel 2.6.38 , but does not work on Kernel 2.6.37 running on ARM processor. And the document gives a different Version information 2.6.6 about the support.

Is there a better way to verify if the Current OS has the support or not ? 
Is it possible the Kernel is trimmed off on Thin client devices.

Comment: You have to recompile the kernel with support for POSIX message queues enabled (`CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE=y`).

Comment: Thanks jxh for your comment. Does this mean the kernel I'm using on ARM is trimmed down to lower the size ? Is there a simpler way to find this out (any commands as such) ?

Comment: Your kernel version supports the feature but complains it's not implemented. I can't think of any other reason this would be besides it being compiled out. Check with the vendor if you need further confirmation.