# How to use "POSIX Message Queues" from Linux kernel in mono?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, ipc, message-queue

POSIX message queues seems to be exactly what I need to pass command line arguments to existing running instance of the same application.

http://man7.org/tlpi/download/TLPI-52-POSIX_Message_Queues.pdf

they're like a Priority-queue channel between currently running processes on the same machine, they don't appear to survive machine restarts in any way
( http://kirkwylie.blogspot.ru/2008/10/posix-message-queues-useful-but-limited.html )

POSIX MQ is supported from Linux Kernel version 2.6.6

CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE=y

( [POSIX Message Queue is supported on which linux Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053243) )

The default Linux implementation has the maximum message size set to 8192 bytes , runtime kernel parameter /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_max

The maximum number of messages you can put into the queue before it starts to block the sender is 10 messages ( /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max )

Linux does not currently (2.6.26) support the use of access control lists (ACLs) for POSIX message queues.
( http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html )

This API is distinct from that provided by System V message queues (msgget(2), msgsnd(2), msgrcv(2), etc.), but provides similar functionality. 
( http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview )

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/how-is-a-message-queue-implemented-in-the-linux-kernel

I don't want to use SystemV queues - [Is it possible use System V Message Queue Linux via Mono C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224426)

Comment: C# here is not a tag, but the language i want to use (an important detail of question). I don't want to cast C# community from windows (and you did that).

Comment: Huh? That's _precisely_ a tag. And that's _precisely_ what the C# tag is used for. To draw C# users to your question.

Comment: Not all C# developers are equally helpful for linux development. Those who are - they are already attracted by mono tag.

Comment: There are only 8 p/invoke funcs and a couple of structures that need defined to use mqueue. I had done a library for that a long time ago... have not used it since.... Now we just mount it let everyone else and use it as a virtual file system, all your standard System.IO.xxx works then. Open/Write/Close a file to it using a 'subdirectory' name as our queue name, and Open/Read/Close/Delete/DIr...

Comment: I don't see your library as a repo, which one i need to search? https://github.com/sushihangover?tab=repositories